# Unusual Chinese Checkers jump that moves three spaces?

Tags: variants, chinese-checkers

I recently found out about a rule where if one marble is 2 spaces away from another, and the next 3 spaces after it are unoccupied, you can jump 3 spaces? So if your marble is in one on the board, and there's another marble, and there are 2 spaces in between, you can jump past it, so there are now 2 in between you, but you are on the other side of the jumped marble? Could anybody point me to an official source of rules to validate this?

Before the move:

[image: Chinese checkers board showing original marble positions]

After both players have performed the three jump move:

[image: Chinese checkers board showing marble position, after both players have performed the 3 space jump]

Comment: In your screenshots, some of these spaces have a little dot in them. What does that represent?

Comment: @doppelgreener, Could be a cursor?

Comment: @doppelgreener that's where the marbles were before the turn was executed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be the [*fast-paced* or *Super Chinese checkers* variant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_checkers#Fast-paced_or_Super_Chinese_checkers) described in Wikipedia.

> While the standard rules allow hopping over only a single adjacent occupied position at a time (as in checkers), this version of the game allows pieces to catapult over multiple adjacent occupied positions in a line when hopping.
>
> In the *fast-paced* or *Super Chinese checkers* variant popular in France, a piece may hop over a *non-adjacent* piece. A hop consists of jumping over a distant piece (friendly or enemy) to a symmetrical position on the opposite side, in the same line of direction. (For example, if there are two empty positions between the jumping piece and the piece being jumped, the jumping piece lands leaving exactly two empty positions immediately beyond the jumped piece.) As in the standard rules, a jumping move may consist of any number of a chain of hops. (When making a chain of hops, a piece is usually allowed to enter an empty corner, as long as it hops out again before the move is completed.)
>
> Jumping over two or more pieces in a hop is not allowed. Therefore, in this variant even more than in the standard version, it is sometimes strategically important to keep one's pieces bunched in order to prevent a long opposing hop.
>
> An alternative variant allows hops over *any* symmetrical arrangement, including pairs of pieces, pieces separated by empty positions, and so on.